# I cannot go to newgame + in infinity blade 2

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I played infinity blade 2. Then I chose new game+. For weeks no problem. I enjoy the fact that I can gain level again, but then suddenly after some sort of update, I am back to the original rebirth with all of my powerful weapons intact.

I pressed new game+ again and it goes back to the original screen (with the same position and stuff). I defeated god king several times again, but I still can't go to new game+. To make things annoying, when I want to play again from the beginning I often accidentally press rather the character slots. That ERASED my old character.

Finally I tried again from the beginning. After defeating god king I still can't do new game+. Then I deleted infinity blade 2. Re-downloaded it, and then played again, defeating god king yet again. I still can't do new game+. Is this a bug? Am I the only one with this issue? The new game+ option is there, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a valid solution, but I think it should help.

IB2 has character slots. I faced a same sort of issue with my IB2 save as well when I updated it. What happened was the update created a NEW character slot, which is why the game began at the original rebirth. You can select your previous character slot.

Go to game menu-> Settings option on the top-right corner -> Character Slots.
Your previous save should be available there as a character slot. Mine sure was.

Hope this helped! Happy Gamin'!